# BroadcastReceiver ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED not firing

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I need my app react after ANY app remove from the device. As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

> ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED
>   Some apps may need to update their stored data when another package is removed; for those apps, there is no good alternative to registering for this broadcast.

I am doing as per there request but the receiver is never called for this action. Please see the code bellow:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BroadcastReceiver testeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"App Uninstalled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };


    registerReceiver(testeReceiver,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED));
}
```

Any idea why or a better approach ?

Thank you guys! =)

Comment: How often other apps are uninstalled in the background? Try creating and registering implicit `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your receiver in your manifiest file because when any app is uninstall on that time it is not guarantee your receiver is register and it will work.

You can register your receiver in the manifest file by using the element:

```
<receiver
   android:name="YOUR_Receiver_CLASS">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="YOUR_ACTION"
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: As per documentation:
" If your app targets Android 8.0 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for most implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that don't target your app specifically). You can still use a context-registered receiver when the user is actively using your app."
But yah ... I've tried it as well and didn't either.

Comment: @RodrigoSalomao isn't ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED a system receiver? it's not restricted on android 8 as this doc show [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)